# Como personalizar uma página de erro 404 no CodeIgniter 2.1.4 utilizando base_url()?

Tags: php, codeigniter, página-de-erro

Gostaria de utilizar uma `página de erro 404` personalizada, mas ao acessar uma imagem utilizando a função `base_url()` não funciona. Como resolver?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acontece isso bastante na comunidade.
Para utilizar o método **base_url()** do helper **url_helper**, no diretório abaixo:

```
/application/errors/
```

Utilize este método:

```
<?= config_item('base_url') ?>
```